# Cross domain issue XMLHttp

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I face the common cross domain issue with xmlhttp.

I am trying to access WSDL web service using the SOAP protocol. I am not using php and so I can not use the

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

I also can't use JSONP as the response I get is not in JSON format but in XML format. 
Is there any other way that I can resolve this issue.

Here is my code snippet.

```
var user1="user_name";
var pass1="******";
var url="http://ideone.com/api/1/service.wsdl";

var soap_msg="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?>"+
"<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'"+          
"xmlns:tns='http://ideone.com:80/api/1/service'    xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/'"+
"xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:wsdl='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/'"+
"xmlns:soap-enc='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/' "+
"xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' >"+
"<SOAP-ENV:Body><mns:getLanguages xmlns:mns='http://ideone.com:80/api/1/service' SOAP-  ENV:encodingStyle='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/'>"+
"<user xsi:type='xsd:string'>"+user1 +"</user><pass xsi:type='xsd:string'>"+pass1+"</pass>"+    
"</mns:getLanguages></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";
var oXmlHttp=  new XMLHttpRequest();
oXmlHttp.open("POST",url,true);
oXmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
oXmlHttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://ideone.com/api/1/service#getLanguages");
oXmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
oXmlHttp.send(soap_msg);
var res=oXmlHttp.responseXML;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have access to, and control of, the server?  If so, what OS?

Comment: @michael Morton No... I don't have access to the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a link from YUI that you will probably find useful.

http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-jsonp-x.html

They've written a callback which is essentially an envelope that allows for XML to be returned.

Comment: Something like this is really your only choice, I think.  You might not want to use the YUI itself, but you can write a JSON wrapper that returns your XML as a string (suitably JSON-encoded of course), and then hand it to a parser.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, Allow Access headers should be set on the server side, that is, on ideone.com which you don't control. At that point, all you can do is along the lines of [easyXDM](http://easyxdm.net).